# Haskell fmap composition misunderstanding

Tags: haskell

If I compose two `fmap`s

```
Prelude> :t (fmap.fmap)
(fmap.fmap)
  :: (Functor f, Functor f1) => (a -> b) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b)
```

I get a function which applies a function to a value inside 2 nested leves of structure, `f1` and `f`.

And I can use it—this works as I expected:

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) (+1) [[1,2]]
[[2,3]]
```

With inferred type as I expected (2 leves of structure around result)

```
Prelude> :t  (fmap.fmap) (+1) [[1,2]]
(fmap.fmap) (+1) [[1,2]] :: Num b => [[b]]
```

The following does not work. I also expect this (because we can't apply `sum` to a single number):

```
Prelude>  (fmap.fmap) sum [[1,2]]

<interactive>:39:2: error:
    • Could not deduce (Num (t0 b))
      from the context: (Num (t b), Num b, Foldable t)
        bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                   (Num (t b), Num b, Foldable t) => [[b]]
        at <interactive>:39:2-24
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall (t :: * -> *) b.
              (Num (t b), Num b, Foldable t) =>
              [[b]]
Prelude> :t  (fmap.fmap) sum [[1,2]]
(fmap.fmap) sum [[1,2]] :: (Num (t b), Num b, Foldable t) => [[b]]
```

BUT! If I change one level of structure to a `Maybe` type:

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]
Just 3
```

then it begins to work, but in my opinion breaking the type signature
`(fmap.fmap) :: (Functor f, Functor f1) => (a -> b) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b)`
(because it applies the `sum` function inside the first level of structure, not the second as I expected).

I think problem in my undersanding how function application order evaluates here, because I find that with parentheses this works as expected inside two levels of structure with foldable list values (vs numbers in first exapmles):

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) sum (Just [[1,2],[2,3]])
Just [3,5]
```

But what happens here:

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]
Just 3
```

1. Why is the first level of stucture skipped?
2. What is the order of function applications here?
3. How does Haskell infer the final type?

   ```
    Prelude> :t (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]
    (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2] :: Num t => Maybe t
   ```

Why `Maybe t` and not `Maybe List t` as I understand `(fmap.fmap)` must determine `f1 (f b)` two levels of structure not one?

Comment: You are confusing `(fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]` with `(fmap.fmap) sum (Just [1,2])`, which would indeed fail for the same reason that `(fmap.fmap) sum [[1,2]]` fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's compute, pretending that numeric literals are `Int`s for the sake of simplicity.

```
(fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]
= fmap (fmap sum) Just [1,2]
        |         |    \ -- an additional argument applied to the result of fmap
        |         \ -- the value with a type of the form f a with f Functor
        \ -- the function to fmap
```

Here, `Just` is a function `[Int] -> Maybe [Int]`, so the first `fmap` operates on the functor `f = (->) [Int]`, we have `fmap = (.)` because that's how it's defined in `Functor ((->) [Int])`.

```
= (.) (fmap sum) Just [1,2]
= (fmap sum) (Just [1,2])
```

Now, `fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)` since that's how `Functor Maybe` is defined.

```
= Just (sum [1,2])
= Just 3
```

> 1. why first level of structure skipped?

It isn't. The first level is `(->) [Int]`.

> 2. what is the order of function applications here?

The usual one. `fmap.fmap` is applied to `sum`. The result is applied to `Just`. The final result is applied to `[1,2]`.

> 3. how does Haskell infer the final type?

It sees that `Just` is a "value wrapped inside the `(->) [Int]` functor", and uses that to instantiate the first `fmap`. The second `fmap` is instead used on the `Maybe` level since `Just` returns that.

Answer (score 6):

What you have just discovered is that **functions are themselves functors**. That statement may sound a bit confusing, so let’s explore this a bit further. Let’s have a look at the function composition operator `(.)`:

```
Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

But now let’s rewrite the type signature slightly:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((->) a b) -> ((->) a c)
```

Here, I’ve behaved as if the function composition arrow were a normal infix operator, and could be placed in front of what look like its ‘type parameters’ (which in fact it can be). And now we notice something interesting — `(.)` looks almost exactly like `fmap`! See:

```
(.)  ::              (b -> c) -> ((->) a b) -> ((->) a c)
fmap :: Functor f => (b -> c) ->  f      b  ->  f      c
```

And in fact it’s possible to write a `Functor` instance for the partially applied function arrow `(->) r` (where `((->) r) a` is the same as `(r -> a)`):

```hs
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
-- type signature here would be:
--  fmap :: (a -> b) -> ((->) r) a -> ((->) r) b
-- that is:
--  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

So, if `f` and `g` are functions, then `fmap f g = f . g`.

Now, how does that relate to your question? Let’s have a look at the expression you’re confused about:

```
Prelude> (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]
Just 3
```

Let’s go through this bit by bit. First, notice that this can be rewritten as: `(fmap (fmap sum) Just) [1,2]`. Now, `fmap sum` is a function — that means it’s a functor! So, using `fmap = (.)` for functions as I said above, this becomes: `((fmap sum) . Just) [1,2]`, that is `fmap sum (Just [1,2])`. And of course that simply evaluates to `Just 3`.

Comment: Functions are not themselves functors. I know what you meant, but I think that statement is confusing.

Comment: Perhaps:  *What you have discovered is that a function type `r -> a` is also a functor in `a`, like `Maybe a`, and so is a "level of structure" for `fmap` to act on.*

Comment: @dfeuer Why not? Last I checked there was a perfectly fine `instance Functor ((->) r)`.

Comment: The (endo)functor consists of a mapping (namely `(->) r`) from objects in **Hask** to objects in **Hask**, along with a mapping, `fmap @((->) r)`, from morphisms (functions) to morphisms. We conventionally just talk about the object mapping. But the morphisms themselves are not functors.

Comment: @dfeuer So in that case, would it also be incorrect to say that ‘`Maybe` is a functor’, since the objects themselves are not functors? (Sorry if I’m misinterpreting what you’re saying — I’m not too good at category theory.)

Comment: A functor has two parts: the mapping of objects and the mapping of morphisms. In **Hask** endofunctors, the latter (`fmap`) is always boring, so we generally identify the former with the functor, and just say "`Maybe` is a functor" or "`(->) r` is a functor". But you wouldn't say that `Just 3` or `(+4)` is a functor.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, I see what you’re saying now — `(->) r` is a functor, but `r -> a` is not. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That's true, but I actually meant that individual functions `r -> a` (such as `fmap sum`) are not themselves functors. *I* know what you meant (I think), but your language could be confusing to a beginner.

Comment: @dfeuer Isn’t that what I just said in my previous comment?

Comment: No, it's not, but perhaps it's what you meant?

Comment: @dfeuer I thought I said that the function `r -> a` — the one in `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)` — is not a functor, but the _type_ `(->) r :: * -> *` _is_ a functor. Could you explain how that is different to what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for answers, it cleans for me that **Just** not **Just [1,2]** goes as second argument to (fmap.fmap).

I want to write type inference as I understand in more details (correct me if I wrong)

We have expression:
(fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2]

the type of (fmap.fmap) is
**(a -> b) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b)**

this determine that it takes two next arguments - **sum** and **Just** and return function.

**sum** has type **List int -> int**  (for simplicity int)
this implies that **a = List int** and **b = int**

Second argument **Just** has type **a -> Maybe a** or another words
**(->) a (Maybe a)** so **f1 = (->) a**  and  **f = Maybe**

this implies that **f1 (f b) = (->) (List int) (Maybe int)**

Or another words the result type of expression
**(fmap.fmap) sum Just** is **List int -> Maybe int**
So the result is function.

And finnaly we apply value [1,2] to this function and get value Just 3 as expected with infered types.